# SQL query in Google App Engine in Java?

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine, jsp, google-cloud-datastore

I have to get all the entities in Google Datastore that fulfill a particular criteria

I have 3 fields:

`marks1, marks2, marks3`

I want the entities that have marks greater than 60 in all the fields

but since datastore allows inequality operator on a single field.

How can I  bypass that..
Please suggest a solution that is not memory or processor intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean property allMarksGreaterThan60 in your entity, and recompute its value each time one of the marks changes.

Comment: I have thought of that ... but what if at some point of time I want to see all having greater than 65 or greater than 60 in 1 and 2 and greater than 65 in marks 3

Comment: @Ashutosh Then you'll need to update your model and your entities. As you observe, App Engine doesn't support inequality filters on multiple properties - there's no magic way around this.

Comment: @Nick So... isn't there a way to make flexible applications in GAE?

Comment: @Ashutosh Certainly - but no app is infinitely flexible, especially when you don't know what you'll want it to do. Adding new features will simply require a mapper run to add new fields, in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, cou can now use Google Cloud Sql. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java for information on how to get up and running on Java. It's basically managed MySQL using standard jdbc to talk to App Engine.